# Creating a bar graph for data comparison in python

Tags: python

For a project I have written a code where a student can input his name, admission number, math , physics and chemistry score. Now I want a bar graph to compare his score to the highest scorer. I have defined a list (l_math, l_chem and l_phy) which is the list of all scores of all the student. I even defined the max scores as: max_math , max_chem and max_phy...

I tried using pandas and changing the code written by Charles Landau:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = "Crime Type Summer|Crime Type Winter".split("|")

# Generate dummy data into a dataframe
j = {x: [random.choice(["ASB", "Violence", "Theft", "Public Order", "Drugs"]
                   ) for j in range(300)] for x in s}
df = pd.DataFrame(j)

index = np.arange(5)
bar_width = 0.35

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
summer = ax.bar(index, df["Crime Type Summer"].value_counts(), bar_width,
            label="Summer")

winter = ax.bar(index+bar_width, df["Crime Type Winter"].value_counts(),
             bar_width, label="Winter")

ax.set_xlabel('Category')
ax.set_ylabel('Incidence')
ax.set_title('Crime incidence by season, type')
ax.set_xticks(index + bar_width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(["ASB", "Violence", "Theft", "Public Order", "Drugs"])
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

But I don't know how to modify this code to use it for my needs...

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by modifying the code you posted, this should do the trick:

```py
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# assuming math, chem, physics ()
student_scores = [9, 1.5, 4.6]
max_score = [9.1, 8.5, 7.8]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'student_scores': student_scores,
    'max_score': max_score
})

index = np.arange(len(df))
bar_width = 0.35
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
summer = ax.bar(index, df["student_scores"], bar_width, label="Student scores")

winter = ax.bar(index+bar_width, df["max_score"], bar_width, label="Max Scores")

ax.set_xlabel('Course')
ax.set_ylabel('Score')
ax.set_title('Current student vs Max score')
ax.set_xticks(index + bar_width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(["Math", "Chem", "Physics"])
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

See that the order in both score lists should be the same.